# Binding Backbone change event to attribute of model in a collection

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I have a view that takes a `collection` like below:

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
       this.collection.on("change://an attribute of a model in aCollectionToRender", someAction);
    }
});

var MyViewInstance = new MyView({
    collection: aCollectionToRender
});
```

Basically, I don't want `MyView` to listen for changes on the entire collection, only a single attribute of the model that the collection contains.

I realize there are a number of alternatives to this:

1. Create views for each model of `aCollectionToRender` and attach `.on("change")` events in those views. I don't want to do this because it's not the right thing to do for my situation
2. Just have a `this.collection.on("change")` event and have the event handler filter based on my requirements. This is less elegant, and if Backbone already allows me to write event filters as I asked above, this is duplicate code

I was just wondering if there's any way to write an event listener that already does the filtering. This question may also be a duplicate; I looked but I didn't find anything exactly like this, however, there are a lot of Backbone questions

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe I am misunderstanding your question, but you can do exactly what you show.  Check out the [Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection).

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
       this.collection.on("change:attributeName", this.someAction /*function to call*/, this);
    },
    someAction: function(model, value, options){
    }
});
```

Comment: Doh! I think you're right! For some reason I thought when it's a collection, the `attributeName` in `change:attributeName` referred to an attribute of the collection, not the model.

Comment: ok, but how can you do this: this.collection.on("change",function(model,property){ //get the property that was changed here... });  ???